# Objective-C. strong vs copy for properties. Fail to receive expected result

Tags: objective-c

I am very new to Objective-C. I am reading Paul Hudson’s book, *Objective-C for Swift Developers.*

In the book, under *Classes* chapter and *Property Attributes* I found this:

> Some of the attributes bear more explanation. For example, why use `copy` rather than `strong`? If you create an `NSMutableString` and assign it to a `strong` property of two different objects, both properties point to the same mutable string. So, if one changes, they both change. This might be what you want in some instances - for example, arrays - but if you want each object to have its own unique properties that cant be changed by surprise, you should use `copy` instead

Just to test it out, here is what I tried to do.
I have a class `Person2` that has a method (`printGreetingsForAllKubas`) to print 3 names assigned to 3 different properties respectively.
`NSString` `nameProperty` that has default attributes
`NSString` `namePropertySame` that also has default attributes
`NSString` `namePropertyCopied` that I gave a `copy` attribute

Then, I did this in my main implementation file.

```objectivec
NSMutableString *mutableName = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Kuba"];

person2.nameProperty        = mutableName;
person2.namePropertySame    = mutableName;
person2.namePropertyCopied  = mutableName;

[person2 printGreetingsForAllKubas];

mutableName = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"John"];
NSLog(@"%@", mutableName);

[person2 printGreetingsForAllKubas];
```

What I did expect, is to firstly print:

> Hello Jakub, and Jakub, and Jakub

The second time, after I changed mutableName to `@"John"` I expected

> Hello John, and John, and Jakub

But it printed out

> Hello Jakub, and Jakub, and Jakub

I would appreciate it if anyone could explain what am I doing wrong. How would I have to write my code that changing the `mutableName` value would affect the result of my printing method?
Many thanks :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```objectivec
mutableName = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"John"];
```

That does not mutate the object. That updates the local `mutableName` variable to point to an entirely new `NSMutableString` instance. Thus, the mutable strings supplied to `person2` will be unchanged as you haven’t mutated that object, but rather created a new one.

If you want to manifest the behavior about which the author was talking, one should mutate the original `NSMutableString` object, e.g., change its `string` property, e.g.

```objectivec
mutableName.string = @"John";
```

This mutates the existing `NSMutableString` object, rather than creating a new instance. In this case, the `person2` properties with `strong` attribute will reflect the mutation (per the cautionary note you reference), but the `person2` properties with `copy` attribute will not have their values changed behind their back.